# How to remove duplicates from MongoDB Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large collection (~2.7 million documents) in mongodb, and there are a lot of duplicates. I tried running `ensureIndex({id:1}, {unique:true, dropDups:true})` on the collection.

It showed me this error:

```
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "too may dups on index build with dropDups=true",
        "code" : 10092
}
```

and main problem is I cannot reinsert the document.

Comment: create new database with unique index, then copy all items via (set continueOnError : true )db.collection1.drop(); // Drop entire other collection
db.collection1_backup.find().forEach(function(doc){
   db.collection1.insert(doc); // start to replace
});

Comment: @Disposer Full answer. It needs it unless you can search for the duplicate.

Comment: I got the Solution by using Java Program 
But Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not a very good solution but you can define a new collection and name it `coll2`.

Define your unique index on it.

read all items from first collection.

```
db.collection.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.awaitData).forEach(function(doc)
{
    db.coll2.insert(doc, {continueOnError: true})
});
```

after that, drop your old collection and rename `coll2` to your old collection name

for 2.7 mil docs, its gonna take some time

Comment: If you are going to iterate all the documents anyway, I think a more straightforward approach would to iterate sorted by the `id` field (assuming that's the field that wants to be unique) and `remove()` duplicate documents (where the current `id` matches the previous one seen). That will avoid the overhead of re-inserting documents that will result in duplicate key errors. As a first step this would require adding a non-unique index on `id` (as there is a 32MB in-memory sort limit) and later dropping & re-adding the index with the unique attribute.

Comment: @Stennie, as I told its not a great solution, but I think as I used the cursor for iterating the result (and didnt use snaphop() and toArray(), its not using 32mb ram

Comment: It's actually my approach that would need the index, since I suggested sorting by the `id` to find uniques when iterating :). It sounds like you meant to use a [snapshot cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/), which will always use the `_id` index. Your current example has the [`awaitdata`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.addOption/) option set, which is for a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/).